# What's causing 405 error for POST method in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to test CRUD operations for an ASP project that I just added WEB.API scaffolding to. I'm testing the operations through Postman. All request methods that came with the scaffolding controllers work and successfully query the database, except for the POST method. Every time I try to insert a new item into a table through Postman I get a 405 error. I'm using raw JSON to insert the query and I have WEBDAV disabled for my IIS. I also tried the method through Fiddler and got the same error. I haven't done anything to change the method, or any of the other methods, so I'm not sure how this is happening or what's causing it.

Here is the controller that I've been testing so far. The only thing I added was the Produces tag at the top.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/contracts")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ContractsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly PortalWizardContext _context;

        public ContractsController(PortalWizardContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Contracts
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Contracts>>> GetContracts()
        {
            return await _context.Contracts.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Contracts/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Contracts>> GetContracts(int id)
        {
            var contracts = await _context.Contracts.FindAsync(id);

            if (contracts == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return contracts;
        }

        // PUT: api/Contracts/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutContracts(int id, Contracts contracts)
        {
            if (id != contracts.ContractId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(contracts).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ContractsExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Contracts
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Contracts>> PostContracts(Contracts contracts)
        {
            _context.Contracts.Add(contracts);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetContracts", new { id = contracts.ContractId }, contracts);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Contracts/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Contracts>> DeleteContracts(int id)
        {
            var contracts = await _context.Contracts.FindAsync(id);
            if (contracts == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Contracts.Remove(contracts);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return contracts;
        }

    }
```

Here is the default route defined in my startup configuration:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Here are the results of the Postman request

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmQiG.png)

[Postman Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Ksq.png)

If I try the request without the ID, then I get a 500 error.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I found the issue. It was server side. There was a constraint in the table script that wouldn't allow the primary key (contractId) to be defined. Instead it's values would be assigned automatically through increments. Once I removed the contractId column from the JSON expression in Postman, it inserted successfully.

Comment: The request should be sent without an ID for the `POST`. Put a breakpoint on the `POST` method, does it hit the method without using the ID?  You get the 405 because there's no method matching `[HttpPost("{id}")]` when you send the request with the ID

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, the breakpoint hits when I run the URL without the ID, but then it gives me a 500 internal server error. It also gives me a 500 error when I include the ID in the request method attribute and run the URL with an ID.

Comment: If it hits the `HttpPost` method, can you step into the method?  What line does it fail on?  You could put `try{} catch (Exception ex){}` inside the method, catch all exceptions and see what the problem is.

Comment: as per your screenshots, you're getting ```405 Method Not Allowed``` and you're passing Header value as DELETE, GET, PUT to a POST method. Please add POST header and remove the Id from URL and put ```try {} catch (Exception ex){}``` in order to see what error you're getting ```_context.SaveChangesAsync();``` here.

Comment: Ok, I removed the ID and put the method's contents in a try-catch expression. Now when I run the URL in Postman, with the same body data, it gives me a 201 created message. However, when I run a GET request or check the database in SQLServer, it's not actually inserting anything into the table. I put breakpoints on the line where it's adding data to the dbcontext, as well as the return statement, and both get hit.

Comment: It also appears that an exception is being thrown when the return statement is reached. It reads: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll"

Comment: Try adding `FromBody` attribute `PostContracts([FromBody] Contracts contracts)`